# lightbox2 is conflicting with scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using LightBox2 for a simple image gallery. I managed to make it work, however now it's conflicting with another javascript script file which I'm referencing from my page.

My script is using `$(document).ready(function () {`

I'm not sure if it's relevant or not however I know that at one point the browser's debugger was complaining about it.

Any insights on this ?

============================================================
I included part of the code that is generating the error. although this was working fine.

var currs = {};

jQuery.noConflict();

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var marketTypeSel = document.getElementById("selMarketType");
    var propertyTypeSel = document.getElementById("selPropertyType");
    var propertyStatusSel = document.getElementById("selPropertyStatus");
    var zoneSel = document.getElementById("selZone");
    var locSel = document.getElementById("selLocalities");
    var currSel = document.getElementById("selCurrency");
    var priceFromSel = document.getElementById("selPriceFrom");
    var priceToSel = document.getElementById("selPriceTo");

    //var data = {};

    marketTypeSel.length = 0;
    propertyTypeSel.length = 0;
    propertyStatusSel.length = 0;
    zoneSel.length = 0;
    locSel.length = 0;
    currSel.length = 0;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Search/LoadInitSearchParameters",
        //data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
```

Comment: Is it conflicting in all browser? Means normally problem occur in IE.

Comment: I am agree with @devtut. Did u tried jQuery.noConflict() ?

Comment: If still its not working, do one thing add all script ref before closing the body tag i.e </body> instead of head tag. I was facing the same problem and this trick work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a jquery no conflict like this below

```
var Jk = jQuery.noConflict();
Jk(document).ready(function (){


});
```

Comment: yep, managed to make it work had an error in my js file, bad day today !! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 jQuery.noConflict();

var Jq = jQuery.noConflict();
Jq(document).ready(function (){


});
```

or

```
JQuery(document).ready(function (){


});
```

simply use `jQuery` instead of `$` when using jquery

Answer (score 0):

If still its not working, do one thing add all script ref before closing the body tag i.e  instead of head tag. I was facing the same problem and this trick work for me.

like below

```
   <body>
        <div>Dummy Data</div>
      <div>Dummy Data</div>
        <script src="/App_Themes/lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/App_Themes/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/App_Themes/lib/jquery.easing.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        //Also lightbox ref
</body>
```

Comment: nope :/ ... nothing will work ... I will try something similar to light box

Answer (score 0):

This is for Lightbox2 2.8.1.

As you're using `jQuery(document).ready(function () {});` this will stop lightbox from initialising.

I found I had to add `lightbox.init()` as my code was stopping lightbox2 from loading.

```
$(function() {
    lightbox.init();
    // other code
}
```